# Automorphism of Upper half plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

> Let $M=\left\{\left.\displaystyle z\mapsto\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\ \right|\ \ ad-bc\not =0\right\}$,$$p:GL(2,\mathbb C)\to M, \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\mapsto\frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$
>   Let $\mathbb H=\left\{z\in\mathbb C|Im(z)>0\right\}$ be the upper half plane. Proof that $p(SL(2,\mathbb R))=Aut(\mathbb H)$.

I tried to show $p(SL(2,\mathbb R))\subset Aut(\mathbb H)$ but failed, because $Im\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)$ is not necassary bigger then zero. Is there another way to show $p(SL(2,\mathbb R))=Aut(\mathbb H)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $$\operatorname{Im}\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{(ad-bc)\cdot\operatorname{Im}z}{\mid cz+d\mid^2}.$$
So $p(SL(2,\mathbb R))\subseteq \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb H).$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $Im (g(z))=\frac{Im (z)}{|cz+d|^2}>0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{H}$ and all $g\in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. So we have a well-defined action of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ on the upper half plane. It is perhaps useful to have a reference for the basics here, see for example [these notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/07_fund_dmn.pdf).

Comment: Is it then enough to say, since $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\alpha +i\beta \in\mathbb H\implies p(SL(2,\mathbb R))=Aut(\mathbb H)$?

Comment: The inverse of $g(z)$ has the same form as $g(z)$, this completes the claim, I guess.

Comment: Yes, the inverse is again an element in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, so of this form.