# finding a function with certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ have poles at $1$ and $-1$, and $f(i)=f(-i)=1$. Elsewhere it is analytic and maps the first quadrant one-to-one onto the upper half plane, second quadrant to the lower half plane, third quadrant to the upper and fourth quadrant to the lower.

Then, I have find all such functions. The answer says $f(z)=-2/(z^2-1)$

However, I think functions of the form $[(1-1/(2d^2))z^2-(1+1/(2d^2))]/(z^2-1)$ where $d$ is any nonzero real number satisfy the given conditions as well. So, the answer is wrong? Could anyone please give me a feedback?

Comment: I think your answer is correct.

Comment: And are the functions I have found the full list of functions satisfying the given condtiions? My argument forces so but I am always not very confident about my logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mapping behavior  and the [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) one can conclude that:
$$
f(\overline z) = \overline{f(z)}\text{ and } f(-\overline z) = \overline{f(z)}
$$
and in particular $f(-z) = f(z)$, i.e. $f$ is an even function. It follows that $f(z) = g(z^2)$ with a meromorphic function $g$ which maps the upper (lower) half-plane one-to-one onto the upper (lower) half-plane, and $g(1) = \infty$, $g(-1) = 1$.

The [automorphisms of the upper half-plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1840351/42969) are well-known:
$$
 g(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}
$$
with $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R$, $ad-bc > 0$. Together with $g(1) = \infty$, $g(-1) = 1$ it follows that
$$
 g(z) = \frac{(1-a)z-(1+a)}{z-1}
$$
for some $a > 0$, and consequently
$$
 f(z) = \frac{(1-a)z^2-(1+a)}{z^2-1} \, .
$$
This is the most general solution, and the same solution that you found, with $a = 1/(2d^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I can get some confidence that I solved in the right way....