# Automorphisms of the half-plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I have trouble with proof of:
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$
$$\Aut(H)=T^{-1} \Aut(D) T $$
via Cayley transformations.
I know that I have to show that:
$$\Phi: \Aut(H)\to \Aut(D) $$
$$f \mapsto T^{-1}\circ f\circ T$$
is a well-defined group homomorphism. Further I have to show that:
$$\Psi:\Aut(D) \to \Aut(H)$$
$$f \to ??$$
is the inverse function of $\Phi$.
$\Phi$ is a group isomorphism and $\Aut(H)=T^{-1}\Aut(D)T$ follows.

Comment: For $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb H)$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840351/automorphism-of-upper-half-plane) and for $\operatorname{Aut}(D)$ of the Klein disc model - well, search here!

Comment: If $\Aut (X)$ is the space of all biholomorphism of $X$, then your claim follow from definition

Comment: But I don't understand how to solve with the definition, because I don't know how to find f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood how to answer this question, we can solve the exercise with the inclusion theorem $$M=N:M⊆NandN⊆M$$
so $$Aut(H)⊆T^{-1}Aut(D)T$$ and the other case.